# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Row 1 has 42 columns, but must have 2

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, laravel-5, google-visualization

> I'm using google bar charts for my project and I create an ajax function to load charts with data. But when I use jquery each function to create data bars in google charts its getting error called 
>   `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Row 1 has 42 columns, but must have 2`. Can Anyone show me the error in my code

This is my chart code

```js
//chart 2
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['bar']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);

function drawChart1() {
  var dataa1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['DS Division', 'No of Youths'],
    $.each(data.locations, function(index, value3) {
      ['' + value3.DSD_Name + '', value3.total]

    }),

  ]);

  var options1 = {
    chart: {

    },
    bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.

    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
  };

  var chart1 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));

  chart1.draw(dataa1, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options1));
}
```

This is my response data from the controller

```js
return response() => json(array(
  'male' => $male,
  'female' => $female,
  'locations' => $locations,
  'salary1' => $salary1,
  'salary2' => $salary2,
  'salary3' => $salary3,
  'salary4' => $salary4,
  'salary5' => $salary5,
  'salary6' => $salary6,
  'employers' => $employers
));
```

Please help me to slove this

Thank You

Comment: You appear to be putting the return value of `.each()` into your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of trying to loop within the array declaration,
use the loop to add values to the array...

```
var chartData = [
  ['DS Division', 'No of Youths'],
];

$.each(data.locations, function(index, value3) {
  chartData.push([value3.DSD_Name, value3.total]);
});

var dataa1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
```